# How to remove HTML table row by value

Tags: html, jquery

Let's say there is a table:

```
<table id="tblPotrawySkladniki">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>banana</td><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>orange</td><td>20</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raspberry</td><td>20</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to remove entire row where i.e. cell1 = orange.
How can I do this using jquery?

Comment: Is there an event that would coordinate with removing the row?

Comment: sorry, I do not understand your question. This table is dynamic and I have not created any events on the table.

Comment: So what would trigger the removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following two examples. Example 1:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tblPotrawySkladniki > tbody td").each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).text() === "orange") {
      $(el).parent().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblPotrawySkladniki">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>banana</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>orange</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>raspberry</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This first example gives you more control over how you compare or seek out the cell. For example, you could use:

```
$(el).text().trim().toLowerCase() === "orange"
```

This would help ensure a case insensitive search.

Example 2:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tblPotrawySkladniki > tbody td:contains('orange')").parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblPotrawySkladniki">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>banana</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>orange</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>raspberry</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The second example relies on the selector and if they do not match exactly, will not find it. It's quick and uses less lines, yet may not always find the needle.

Each of these, in their own way, will target the Cell and remove the parent Row. See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/text/
- https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: in my case this worked well: $("#tblPotrawySkladniki > tbody > tr:contains('"+ nazwaProduktu +"')").remove()

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic way of doing it. For example, enter Orange or Raspberry into the input and click enter.

```js
$(function() {


$("#inputSearch").on('change', function(){
var v = $(this).val();
    $('#tblPotrawySkladniki tr td').filter(function() {
        if ($(this).text() === v) {
            return true;
        }
    }).parent().remove();
});

})
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="inputSearch">Search Value:</label>
<input type="text" name="inputSearch" id="inputSearch">


<table id="tblPotrawySkladniki">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>banana</td><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>orange</td><td>20</td></tr>
    <tr><td>raspberry</td><td>20</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Be mindful that `.html()` will return all the HTML content. Might consider using `.text()` to ensure you do not get `<span>orange</span>` as a result, the comparrison would be `false`.

Comment: @Twisty thanks for you input. Much appreciated.